# What is the best way to store an array with id's related to another table in a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database, relationship

I'm building an application with Laravel to predict the order of outcomes of a competition. So I made a table with participants and now I want a user to predict the order of outcome of the participants and save it to the database.

So for example there are 6 participants ( in database table ) and I want to predict the outcome. I would say:

1. Participant 4
2. Participant 5
3. Participant 2
4. Participant 1
5. Participant 6
6. Participant 3

I've made a table called 'predictions' and there I want to save a 'User ID' and the prediction. Actually it is an array with ID's of the participants. But what is the best way to save and retrieve this?

Thanks so much for help.

Ronald.

Comment: 3 columns; `user_id`, `participant_id`, `placement`. `User` can have many `Prediction`, each `Prediction` has a `Participant`, and when displaying, order the returned `predictions` by `placement`. Generally, try to avoid saving an array to a database, and use proper relational db practices.

Comment: Wow, that's actually very simple but solid solution. So you suggest to use a pivot table?

Comment: I suppose it would be; the naming convention and tables would be non-standard (generally you'd name the pivot table as it relates to the tables it links, like `users_participants`), but it would still be a `many-to-many` between `User` and `Participant`, with an additional column for specifying the order.

Comment: Thank you! I managed with it, but not with a many-to-many, but with a belongsTo.
A user can make one prediction, so a user hasMany predictions (because of multiple rows), but a prediction belongsTo a User and belongsTo a Participant.

Comment: Nice! I *think* that's what I was eluding to in the first comment, but it's a little harder to visualize without the schema/models and whatnot. Glad you got it working. You are more than welcome to post how you accomplished this as a self-answer (include the schema, or local/foreign key values, and the Models with relationship logic if you can)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Tim for your answer and of course I'll show you what I did.

So I had a usual User model and a Participant model. What I needed was a connection between a User that predicts the outcome / ranking of a Participant model:

Example:
- I am a User ( Ronald )
- There are 6 Participants ( P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6 )
- I have to predict in which order the Participants will 'cross the finish line'.

So I made a table, on suggestion of Tim, called 'predictions' with a model Prediction. And there I will store the User - Participant - Predicted ranking.

**In the near future I'll take a look at how I can store multiple predictions. For now one is ok!**

The Schema will look like this:

```
Schema::create('predictions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('participant_id');
    $table->unsignedTinyInteger('position');
    $table->foreign('user_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('users');
    $table->foreign('participant_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('participants');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

And this is how the Prediction model looks like:

```
class Prediction extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function participant()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Participant');
    }
}
```

So when I'm logged in I can get my prediction by doing:

```
Auth::user()->predictions()->orderBy('position')->get();
```

And when I have a Prediction, I can get the participant of the prediction by:

```
$prediction->participant;
```

And the user of the prediction by:

```
$prediction->user;
```

But now I can only do one prediction per user. I'll have to find a way to link a User to a Prediction and then the Participant - Position combination to a Prediction.

So I can say get all the predictions of the user. Maybe somebody ( or Tim ;) ) have a suggestion?!

Thank you and I hope someone can find some answers to in my answer.

Cheers.